# mysql-connector-odbc-8.1.0-winx64 installer does not recognize that visual studio c++ 2019 is installed

Tags: mysql-connector

mysql odbc driver installer does not recognize that visual studio c++ 2019 is installed:

[image]

However, I installed the official version of Visual Studio C++ 2019-2022 from the Microsoft page and it is installed:

[image]

How can I proceed?

I tried installing previous versions and also repairing the file.